# Find items missing from table

Tags: join, query

Long time reader, first-time posting.  This seems like a simple search but I can't find the answer I need, and the ones that make sense aren't giving me the desired result.

I'm almost embarrassed to ask this becasue it has GOT to be the easiest code in the world but I just can't seem to get it?!

I have 2 tables:  ContractType, Inventory

Contract Type:

```
╔════════╦════════╗
║ TypeID ║ InvtID ║
╠════════╬════════╣
║ A      ║ APPLE  ║
║ A      ║ ORANGE ║
║ A      ║ PEAR   ║
║ B      ║ APPLE  ║
║ B      ║ ORANGE ║
║ C      ║ ORANGE ║
╚════════╩════════╝
```

Inventory:

```
╔════════╗
║ InvtID ║
╠════════╣
║ APPLE  ║
║ ORANGE ║
║ PEAR   ║
╚════════╝
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get a list of TypeID's that are missing items on Inventory, like so:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ ct.TypeID ║ ct.InvtID ║ i.InvtID ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ A         ║ APPLE     ║ APPLE    ║
║ A         ║ ORANGE    ║ ORANGE   ║
║ A         ║ PEAR      ║ PEAR     ║
║ B         ║ APPLE     ║ APPLE    ║
║ B         ║ ORANGE    ║ ORANGE   ║
║ B         ║           ║ PEAR     ║
║ C         ║           ║ APPLE    ║
║ C         ║ ORANGE    ║ ORANGE   ║
║ C         ║           ║ PEAR     ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Here's my attempt, where am I going wrong?

```
SELECT ct.typeid [CTTypeID], 
       ct.invtid [CTInvtID], 
       i.invtid  [InvtID] 
FROM   contracttype ct 
       FULL OUTER JOIN inventory i 
                    ON ct.invtid = i.invtid
```

I don't even need it in the format above, I just need to know that Type B is missing PEAR & Type C is missing Apple & Pear.

Comment: Where is `TypeId` coming from?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum, please add CREATE TABLE and INSERTS to set up your example, and the desired result. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing where `TypeId` is coming from this won't be 100% complete. It looks like there may be an error in the data model, but I understand these are often abstractions/homework questions so the parent entity might not exist.

You need to Cross Join `TypeId` and `InvtId` to create all possible combinations, then left join `ContractType`:

```
SELECT
  tp.TypeId
 ,inv.InvtId
 ,contype.InvtId
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      TypeId
    FROM
      ContractType
  ) tp
CROSS JOIN
  Inventory inv
LEFT JOIN
  ContractType contype
    ON contype.TypeId = tp.TypeId
        AND contype.InvtId = inv.InvtId
```

If `TypeId` is coming from another entity where it is the primary key, then you would reference that instead of doing the `SELECT DISTINCT` in the subquery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, TypeID is on the CONTRACTTYPE table.   Column A lists the TypeID and Column B lists all InvtID under that type.   The answer you provided works PERFECT.   Thank you!